# Converting a study into a strategy on pinescript

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, trading, algorithmic-trading

Im trying to build a strategy with an indicator from lazy bear on pinescript. The code looks like this:

```
//@version=5

strategy(title='Volume Flow Indicator [LazyBear]', shorttitle='VFI_LB', overlay = true)

length = input(130, title='VFI length')
coef = input(0.2)
vcoef = input(2.5, title='Max. vol. cutoff')
signalLength = input(5)
smoothVFI = input(false)

if ta.sma(x, y) >= smoothVFI
    ta.sma(x, y)
else 
    X
   // sma_1 = ta.sma(x, y)
   // smoothVFI ? sma_1 : x

typical = hlc3
inter = math.log(typical) - math.log(typical[1])
vinter = ta.stdev(inter, 30)
cutoff = coef * vinter * close
vave = ta.sma(volume, length)[1]
vmax = vave * vcoef
vc = if volume < vmax
    volume
else
    vmax  //min( volume, vmax )

mf = typical - typical[1]

vcp = if mf > cutoff
    vc
if mf < -cutoff
    vc * -1
else
    0

vfi = ta.sma(math.sum(vcp, length) / vave, 3)
vfima = ta.ema(vfi, signalLength)
d = vfi - vfima

plot(0, color=color.new(color.gray, 0), style=plot.style_cross)
showHisto = input(false)
plot(showHisto ? d : na, style=plot.style_histogram, color=color.new(color.gray, 50), linewidth=3)
plot(vfima, title='EMA of vfi', color=color.new(color.orange, 0))
plot(vfi, title='vfi', color=color.new(color.green, 0), linewidth=2)
```

These are my current mistakes and I do not know how to fix them.
Fehler in 11:11 Undeclared identifier 'x'
Fehler in 11:14 Undeclared identifier 'y'
Fehler in 14:5 Undeclared identifier 'X'
Fehler in 11:20 Cannot call 'operator >=' with argument 'expr1'='smoothVFI'. An argument of 'input bool' type was used but a 'simple float' is expected.

My idea is that I just want to do some backtesting on how it works to simply enter a long trade when the vfi crosses the zero above. Its not a standalone idea, I just want to implement that indicator into other strategies Im currently trading. Does anybody know how to fix these errors? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far and what error messages you get. We are not here to the job for you.

Comment: Hey - so I changed the version to V5 that causes some red errors on the code. I tried to fix them one after the other, but there are always new errors. 

The problem is, that I dont understand the code. There are functions like iff - and I can not easily transfer them to if.

To me it looks like the code is from version 1 and I can not transfer it automatically to version 5. Do you have any tips for me how to do it? Or what my next steps should look like? I just basically want to work this code in V5

Comment: Use the tips mentioned [here](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/migration_guides/index.html) to upgrade it to v3. After that, use the auto converter tool.

Comment: Ok that helped a lot. Just one question - I do not understand what that means:
ma(x,y) => smoothVFI ? sma(x,y) : x

If you check the code above, x & y are not defined anywhere. Can you help me with that?

Comment: Because right now, I always get a mistake in V5 "Undeclared identifier "x" " (or y)

Comment: if ta.sma(x, y) >= smoothVFI
    ta.sma(x, y)
else 
    X

Comment: Thats how I changed it in V5

Comment: Update your question with the code you have so far please.

Comment: Thanks for showing some effort. Retracted my close and down votes. The way you converted `ma(x,y)` in the original code was wrong. Provided an answer for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below line in the original code is actually a function and not a call to `ta.sma()` (in `v5`).

```
ma(x,y) => smoothVFI ? sma(x,y) : x
```

So, you should write this also as a function.

Below code is the correct way of upgrading this code to `v5`:

```
//@version=5
indicator(title = "Volume Flow Indicator [LazyBear]", shorttitle="VFI_LB")

length = input(130, title="VFI length")
coef = input(0.2)
vcoef = input(2.5, title="Max. vol. cutoff")
signalLength=input(5)
smoothVFI=input.bool(false)

ma(x,y) => smoothVFI ? ta.sma(x,y) : x

typical=hlc3
inter = math.log( typical ) - math.log( typical[1] )
vinter = ta.stdev(inter, 30 )
cutoff = coef * vinter * close
vave = ta.sma( volume, length )[1]
vmax = vave * vcoef

vc = if (volume < vmax)
    volume
else
    vmax //min( volume, vmax )

mf = typical - typical[1]

vcp = if (mf > cutoff)
    vc
else
    if (mf < -cutoff)
        -vc
    else
        0

vfi = ma(math.sum( vcp , length )/vave, 3)
vfima=ta.ema( vfi, signalLength )
d=vfi-vfima

plot(0, color=color.gray, style=plot.style_circles)
showHisto=input.bool(false)
plot(showHisto ? d : na, style=plot.style_histogram, color=color.new(color.gray, 50), linewidth=3)
plot( vfima , title="EMA of vfi", color=color.orange)
plot( vfi, title="vfi", color=color.green,linewidth=2)
```

Comment: Thank you very , very much vitruvius! That helped a lot and I also learned something. You are awesome!